# Parallelism in "whether... or not" sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis, parallelism, correlative-conjunctions

We have an exercise on parallelism involving rewriting sentences correctly; there's this one sentence I'm unsure as how to rewrite.

> Mother cannot decide whether she will allow Cecil to attend the party or not because of the bad weather condition.

Would the following be a proper correction?

*Mother cannot decide whether or not to allow Cecil to attend the party because of the bad weather condition.*

I honestly can't find faulty parallelism in the original sentence, so an explanation will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think it needs correcting?

Comment: It's good to place "or not" after whether, but most people would consider the "or not" unnecessary.

Comment: << Because of the bad weather conditions, mother cannot decide whether or not she will allow Cecil to attend the party. >> is certainly correct.

Comment: The problem with the first sentence is that "or not" is too far from "whether" to sound graceful. The OP's edit is grammatically correct. Although "whether or not" is a common phrase, "whether" alone conveys a possibility either positive or negative.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing technically wrong with

> whether or not

Another version that has recently (by historical standards, anyway) has fallen into disuse is

> whether or no

That said, in cases where "or not" is implied (such as in your example), omitting "or not" sounds more elegant. Brevity is poetry's first cousin.